# php mkdir() Permission denied when used as recursive

Tags: php, permissions, nested, permission-denied, mkdir

When I use this code in console:

```
php -r 'mkdir("./test", 0655, true);'
```

It works without any problem

but this fails:

```
php -r 'mkdir("./test/boo", 0655, true);'
```

with the error:

> Permission denied in Command line code on line 1

Why when I want to make a nested dir tree, even I use **true** as third parameter I get permission denied error?

How to create nested dir tree with the **mkdir()** ?

I'm using PHP 7.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to work with directories you need execute permission ([Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)) if you don't have execute permission you can't change into the directory which is a bit limiting.  So you need to create them with 755 permissions...

```
php -r 'mkdir("./test", 0755, true);'
```